# PlatformException(No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE

Tags: flutter

I GOT THIS ERROR WHEN I PRESS THE BUTTON

E/flutter (23344): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE typ=*/* flg=0x10000001 pkg=com.whatsapp clip={*/* {U(content)}} (has extras) }, null, null, null)
E/flutter (23344): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
E/flutter (23344): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
E/flutter (23344): 
E/flutter (23344): #2      WhatsappShare.shareFile (package:whatsapp_share2/whatsapp_share2.dart:78:9)
E/flutter (23344): 
E/flutter (23344): #3      _ProductDetailsScreenState.build. (package:multi_vendor_shop/screen/productDetailsScreen.dart:272:33)
E/flutter (23344):

```
                MYCODES
    
            InkWell(  onTap: () async {
                            final imageUrl = widget
                                .productModel!.imageUrls![pageNumber!];
                            final url = Uri.parse(imageUrl);
                            final response = await http.get(url);
                            final bodyBytes = response.bodyBytes;
                            final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
                            final zePath = '${tempDir.path}/image.jpg';
                            File(zePath).writeAsBytesSync(bodyBytes);

                            await WhatsappShare.shareFile(
                              phone: _phone,
                              text: 'I NEED HELP',
                              filePath: [zePath],
                            );

                          },
                          child: const Icon(
                            FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp,
                          ),
                        ),
```

Comment: Is Whatsapp installed?

Comment: Yes, i have  Gb_whatsup

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As you can see the above code,  i want to share image file from that url to specific number on whatsup, I have used whatsup.sharefile as my codes seen,  i got that error when i run the code.